# How to instantiate private / hidden Objective C framework class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, private

If you perform a [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) of AppKit it reveals multiple private / hidden classes defined in that framework.

One example is the following class:

```
__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface _NSFullScreenWindow : NSWindow
{
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow;

@end
```

How do you create an instance of a class that is intended to be private / hidden in Objective-C?

*I know that private / hidden classes are not meant to be accessed, so no need for moral lessons.*

Comment: Is everything ok with your MacOS app setup? I can instantiate `id object = [NSClassFromString(@"_NSFullScreenWindow") new]` without problems.

Comment: @Kamil.S I need to look at it again, I created a new Cocoa project and tested it and just got 0x0 as class back.

Comment: @Kamil.S I just ran the same code as I have in my question today and I actually got a reference to the class, must have done some mistake yesterday when inspecting the variable. Thank you!

Comment: @Kamil.S I moved the code from the question to the answer since it was working as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the class by name and instantiate it as following:

```
Class winClass = NSClassFromString(@"_NSFullScreenWindow");
id win = [winClass new];
```

Win will be a pointer to an instance of _NSFullScreenWindow after running that code.